# How to insert an element into xml column not knowing if the tree will already exist?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a table of values in SQL Server 2008 from which I wish to insert the value into an XML column within a matching row of another table. The xml column may or may not have all the tags leading up to the element I want to insert.

I can achieve this through multiple update / `xml.modify` statements to ensure the tags exist prior to inserting the element, but that seems really inefficient and what if I wanted to insert an element 5 or 10 tags deep?

Here's a created [example in SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03812/1)

The setup is that I have 2 tables (simplified/made up here to make an understandable scenario)

```
CREATE TABLE tableColors (id nvarchar(100), color  nvarchar(100))
CREATE TABLE xmlTable (id nvarchar(100), xmlCol xml)`
```

I need to insert the element `<root><colors><color>tableColors.color</color></colors></root>` into xmlTable where the id matches and the element doesn't already exist. The xmlCol can contain many more elements or even be blank. The color tag is 0 or many and the colors tag is 0 or 1.

The final statement to insert the element in the right place makes sense, but won't work if the parent tags don't already exist.

```
UPDATE xmlTable
SET xmlCol.modify(' insert <color>{sql:column("color")}</color> as first into (/root/colors)[1] ')
FROM xmlTable
INNER JOIN tableColors ON xmlTable.id = tableColors.id
WHERE xmlCol.exist('/root/colors/color[(text()[1]) = sql:column("color")]') = 0
```

So, I need to ensure `/root/colors` exists before running this update statement. Please tell me I'm missing something and I don't have to explicitly do an insert of root (if empty) and then insert colors into root.

To further explain, here's a before and after of inserting the new element into /root/colors:

```
New Element              XML before                                           XML after
<color>blue</color>       -blank-                                              <root><colors><color>blue</color></colors></root>
<color>green</color>      <root><vegitation>yes</vegitation></root>            <root><vegitation>yes</vegitation><colors><color>green</color></colors></root>
<color>white</color>      <root><colors><color>brown</color></colors></root>   <root><colors><color>brown</color><color>white</color></colors></root>
```

Again, here's a full [example in SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03812/1) where I achieve what I want, but there has to be a better way. What am I missing?

Comment: It's starting to look like Brian's answer below is about as close as XML will take us. i.e. multiple if statements within a single update - a single update is great, but doing this for more complex trees would be a nightmare. I know I said I won't accept an answer that uses dynamic SQL, but I thought I might convert Brian's answer to a stored proc that uses dynamic SQL to eliminate the repetition and open this up to other trees & columns. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8e66/1 Still hoping someone will put forward an even simpler XML statement :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the nesting structure in your insert statement and do it with just one update like this:

```
UPDATE #xmlTable
SET xmlCol.modify('
insert if (count(/root)=0) then <root><colors><color>{sql:column("color")}</color></colors></root> 
else (if (count(/root/colors)=0) then <colors><color>{sql:column("color")}</color></colors> 
else <color>{sql:column("color")}</color>) as first into 
(if (count(/root)=0) then (/) else (if (count(/root/colors)=0) then (/root) else (/root/colors)))[1]')
FROM #xmlTable
INNER JOIN #tableColors
    ON #xmlTable.id = #tableColors.id
WHERE xmlCol.exist('/root/colors/color[(text()[1])=sql:column("color")]') = 0
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, this does at least remove all the additional updates! You may have the best SQL XML based solution possible, though this would rapidly become unfathomable if you needed to insert something more than 5 levels deep. The need to if - then - else at all for this seems like a big oversight from MS. I hadn't considered 2 lots of if - then - else, one for the insert, the other for the if. Great thinking! Here's your code in SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03812/8

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use an XSL transformation to manipulate the XML. Here is an old blog (SQL Server 2005) about integrating transformation using SQL CLR (there is lots of other information out there):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mrorke/archive/2005/06/28/433471.aspx

Once you have integrated this your query could look something like:

```
update @xmlTable
set xmlCol = case 
    when cast(xmlCol as varchar(max)) = ''
        then '<root><colors><color>' + color + '</color></colors></root>'
    else {run xslt transformation, passing in @tableColors.color as XSLT parameter colorForUpdate}
    end
from @xmlTable x
inner join @tableColors y on x.id = y.id
```

And the stylesheet to handel non-empty instances of xmlCol could look somthing like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>       

<xsl:param name="colorForUpdate"/>              

<xsl:template match="/root[not(colors)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <colors>
            <color>
                <xsl:value-of select="$colorForUpdate"/>
            </color>
        </colors>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root/colors">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <color>
        <xsl:value-of select="$colorForUpdate"/>
    </color>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Appreciate the effort you've gone to there and I am sure a CLR solution is possible. It just seems to me that having to create an XSLT and CLR for this is a lot more work than just multiple insert statements. Especially as this still doesn't become a generic approach to merging (not that I asked for that, just that the extra effort would need to take this to another level). The extra files to deploy, install and manage external to SQL is an issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query :

```
UPDATE xmlTable
SET xmlTable.xmlCol = (
    SELECT
        CAST(REPLACE(x.myXML, '&myColor;', c.color) AS XML)
    FROM (
        SELECT *, 
            CASE
                WHEN xmlTable.xmlCol.exist('root') = 0 THEN 
                    '<root><colors><color>&myColor;</color></colors></root>'
                WHEN xmlTable.xmlCol.exist('root/colors') = 0 THEN
                    REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), xmlTable.xmlCol), '<root>','<root><colors><color>&myColor;</color></colors>')
                ELSE
                    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), xmlTable.xmlCol)
            END AS myXML
        FROM 
            xmlTable) x
        JOIN
        tableColors c
        ON x.id = c.id
    WHERE
        xmlTable.id = x.id)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I had considered using replace statements also, but thought there would be a simple xml query solution that could avoid such things. Here it is in SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03812/16 A couple of notes on your answer, it is close to working, but the else statement would also need to be a replace '<colors>', '<colors><color>...', need to avoid inserting a duplicates and I think it could be simplified greatly. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03812/19 for my simplifications.

Comment: @ScottC I change my query to an update query, now it will update your xmlCol ;).

Answer (score 0):

This is just building upon Brian's answer which appears to be the only single XML query based solution currently possible.  For me - at least for now - the single statement is enough, but if you need to insert a tree deeper into an xml structure, it would become really painful and automating this makes some degree of sense.

See my example [in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d8e66/1). Here I have created a stored proc which takes the xml tree and column as parameters to create and execute a dynamic SQL query. The benefits being that you can use the same SP to insert different trees, from different columns or easily change the tree without worry that you've missed one of the if statements. Naturally the normal issues of dynamic SQL apply and should be taken into consideration - e.g. lack of execution plans, etc. You could easily make this even more generic by also taking the table name/join clauses as a parameter.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future, alter the table names to suit your needs. Here's the code (in case SQL Fiddle forgets).

```
-- @xmlTree should be of the format '/root/colors/color', column is where to get the data from in the tableFacts table
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insertXML(@xmlTree nvarchar(max), @column sysname)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @insert nvarchar(max), @if nvarchar(max), @val nvarchar(max), @into nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @xmlColumn nvarchar(max)='sql:column("' + @column +'")'
    DECLARE @parentTree nvarchar(max)=@xmlTree
    DECLARE @endTree nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @closeTags nvarchar(max)=''
    DECLARE @thisTag nvarchar(max) 

    WHILE (LEN(@parentTree)>0)
    BEGIN
        -- Set each parameter
        SET @thisTag = RIGHT(@parentTree,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@parentTree))-1)
        SET @endTree = @thisTag + COALESCE('/' + @endTree, '')
        SET @closeTags = @closeTags + '</' + @thisTag + '>'
        SET @parentTree = LEFT(@parentTree,LEN(@parentTree)-LEN(@thisTag)-1)

        -- Set the insert and into statements
        SET @if = 'if (count(' + @parentTree + '/' + @thisTag + ')=0) then '
        SET @val = '<' + REPLACE(@endTree,'/','><') + '>{' + @xmlColumn + '}' + @closeTags
        SET @insert = COALESCE(@if + @val + ' 
    else ' + @insert, @val)
        SET @into =  CASE WHEN @into IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'if (count(' + @parentTree + '/' + @thisTag + ')=0) then ' END + ' (' + 
            CASE @parentTree WHEN '' THEN '/' ELSE @parentTree END + ')' + COALESCE(' else ' + @into,'')
    END

    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE xmlTable
    SET xmlCol.modify('' insert ' + @insert + ' into (' + @into + ')[1]'')
    FROM xmlTable
    INNER JOIN tableFacts
        ON xmlTable.id = tableFacts.id
    WHERE xmlCol.exist(''' + @xmlTree + '[(text()[1])=' + @xmlColumn + ']'') = 0 
      AND ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(@column) + ','''') <> ''''' 

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
```